# Why in Ubuntu(Wub)i does it skip windows when I update grub?

Tags: boot, windows

I set it to not show the os menu so now I need a solution to get this sorted without a disc recovery because i don't have one!is their a way to sort this through the "Terminal"app on Ubuntu (I used wubi to install)Please do not say anything with a recovery cd because I do not have that kind of facility with this laptop

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:
Install Ubuntu newly (normal install) side by side to your windows wubi OS. Than you should be able to get the grub menu with the option to boot into windows. Afterwards you could use Easy BCD to recover the windows MBR and delete the fresh Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0):

Download `bootrepair` for ubuntu. Use "Recommended" repair option. When it is done use `EasyBCD` to put back winOS in charge.

These tools are simple to use but can also mess up your computer if you don't know how to use them.